# Completely disable py.test stdin/stdout capturing, within a test (similar to py.test -s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

*(This is meant as a much more specific version of [How can I make py.test tests accept interactive input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41194262/5043387)).*

I'm using py.test, and I'm trying to make stdin and stdout work as normally -- i.e. print() should immediately print to the terminal, and input() (this is Python 3.5) should accept a line of input interactively.

(I am trying to make my test cases do this, I know this isn't normal for unit testing, I am *not* trying to have my testcases test something else that uses stdin and stdout).

Running pytest with the -s flag does pretty much what I want, but I would rather have this as an option set within my test modules or individual test functions. Especially as I only want to use it on some tests. capsys.disabled() as context manager doesn't cut it -- it only deals with stdout and stderr, not stdin.

Is there a way to do this, either a pytest option to call via marker/decorator/context manager, or a way to "re-connect" sys.stdin/stdout within my module?

Thank you.

Comment: I've communicated with the developers. The inability to do this may actually be a bug in py.test.

Answer (score -2):

http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html provides how to disable the stdout capturing:

```
def test_disabling_capturing(capsys):
    print('this output is captured')
    with capsys.disabled():
        print('output not captured, going directly to sys.stdout')
    print('this output is also captured')
```

Comment: This handles stdout just fine.  However, it doesn't help with stdin. So print() works, but input() doesn't.

Comment: You a right, somehow I missed the input part. I actually doubt there is a solution, as to me this seems to contradict the concept of unittests. They should ensure a standard which is tested.
Maybe you just want to `mock` the `input` function, and provide a fixed input?

Comment: Not in this case. But maybe I might be able to somehow mock the input function, or stdin. back into being actual stdin.

Comment: @DerWeh when mocking `input`, pytest raises OSError anyway.