# Cant receive input in def function - python

Tags: python, input, pytest

```
def play(game_words):
    print("Welcome to Game")
    num_attempts = int(input('Enter numvber of attempts: ')) 
    print(num_attempts)
```

for some reason when I run it i receive an error like this on num_attempts line -

```
  guessed_letter = input('Enter numvber of attempts:  ')
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <_pytest.capture.DontReadFromInput object at 0x00000199ED773750>
size = -1

  def read(self, size: int = -1) -> str:
>       raise OSError(
            "pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`."
        )
E       OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.
```

I know there is nothing wrong with this simple code so why am I getting this?

thanks for the help!

Tried to run it in a diffrent function didnt work.

Comment: The code is fine; `pytest` by default sets standard input to a non-readable object while it executes your code. The error message provides one solution, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41194262/1126841 as well.

Comment: have you considered using `-s` when running with pytest, which quite literally what the error says?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `pytest`, and as it says, you should use `-s`. So, when calling your file, you would do the following: `pytest -s whatever_your_file_is.py`.

Alternatively, you could use [`from unittest.mock import patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), which would allow you to pre-define the inputs.

**Also**, given that **it doesn't seem like you actually want to test**, you could ensure you are not using `pytest`.